# Function calling firebase object always returns true

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Im trying to compare 2 firebase objects countregs and maxregs. I want to return a boolean like this, but I always get true not matter the values.
If a print the values it shows countregs = 3 and maxregs = 5 so it should return false.

Thanks!

```
getMaxRegs(company: string) {
    var snapshotMaxRegs = this.db.object(`companies/${company}/maxregs`,{ preserveSnapshot: true})

    snapshotMaxRegs.subscribe(snapshot => {
        console.log('maxRegs = '+ snapshot.val())
        return snapshot.val();
    });
}

getCountRegs(company: string){
    var snapshotCountRegs = this.db.object(`companies/${company}/countregs`,{ preserveSnapshot: true})

    snapshotCountRegs.subscribe(snapshot => {
        console.log('currRegs = '+ snapshot.val())
        return snapshot.val();
    });
}

maxRegsReached(company: string){
    if (this.getCountRegs(company) >= this.getMaxRegs(company)
        || this.getCountRegs(company) == this.getMaxRegs(company))
    {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both your functions `getCountRegs` and `getMaxRegs` return `undefined`, the only `return` statements they contain are nested inside callback functions and the functions that they call are asynchronous. You need to start thinking asynchronously:

```
async getMaxRegs(company: string): Promise<number> {
  const snapshotMaxRegs = this.db.object(`companies/${company}/maxregs`,{
    preserveSnapshot: true});

  return snapshotMaxRegs.map(snapshot => snapshot.val()).toPromise();
}

getCountRegs(company: string): Promise<number> {
  const snapshotCountRegs = this.db.object(`companies/${company}/countregs`,{
    preserveSnapshot: true});

  return snapshotCountRegs.map(snapshot => snapshot.val()).toPromise();  
}

async maxRegsReached(company: string) : Promise<boolean>{
  const count = await this.getCountRegs(company);
  const max = await this.getMaxRegs(company);
  return count >= max; 
}
```

and then to call `this.maxRegsReached()` the calling function must also be declared `async` and must `await` the result.

And always keep in mind that the `await` means all of your other code can run while waiting for the result.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `getMaxRegs` and `getCountRegs` technically does not return anything, you won't be able to do a meaningful comparison.

What you should do is return an Observable in `getMaxRegs` and `getCountRegs` method using `.map()` instead of subscribing to it. And then, you can join the two observables (using `.forkJoin`) in `maxRegsReached()` and compare the two values returned.

```
getMaxRegs(company: string) {
    var snapshotMaxRegs = this.db.object(`companies/${company}/maxregs`,{ preserveSnapshot: true})

    return snapshotMaxRegs.map(snapshot => {
        console.log('maxRegs = '+ snapshot.val())
        return snapshot.val();
    });
}

getCountRegs(company: string){
    var snapshotCountRegs = this.db.object(`companies/${company}/countregs`,{ preserveSnapshot: true})

    return snapshotCountRegs.map(snapshot => {
        console.log('currRegs = '+ snapshot.val())
        return snapshot.val();
    });
}

maxRegsReached(company: string){

    return Observable.forkJoin([
        this.getCountRegs(company),
        this.getMaxRegs(company)
    ]).map((joined)=>{
        let countRegs = joined[0];
        let maxRegs = joined[1];

        return countRegs >= maxRegs;
    })
}
```

Now you would need to subscribe to `maxRegsReached` to get the results:

```
this.maxRegsReached('company name').subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result) //true or false
})
```

Comment: Note that you still don't have anything being returned from `maxRegsReached`.

Comment: @Duncan You are right. I automatically assume he is using `maxRegsReached` as button call or something. My bad.

Comment: You could even do: `.map([countRegs, maxRegs] => countRegs >= maxRegs)` and save on the misspelling of `joined`.

Comment: @Duncan good idea, just want to be more explicit if OP can't follow the code

Comment: Thanks! But Im trying to print the result but nothing :(     `code`this.authData.maxRegsReached(this.signupForm.value.company).subscribe(result => {
        console.log('result = ' + result) //true or false
    })`code`